# Arduino Uno Board not showing up under my ports, or in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to use an Arduino board (brand new), but it doesn't show up as an available port to write to connect to. Under my boards it doesn't show up, but it shows up under "Other Devices" as "ATmega16u2 DFU"

I've read online that the firmware needs to be updated, and I followed the instructions on the following link:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2

The link to the latest firmware is broken. How else can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the drivers? if it is an original arduino board, inside the IDE installation folders you will find the drivers.

Comment: I have, there is a different board I have that works on the same computer